Continuity from above measure and a doubt on how to conclude the proof
Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ a measurable space, $\mu:\mathcal{M}\to [0+\infty]$ a positive measure.
Theorem. Let's consider a family $\{E_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, with $E_n\in \mathcal{M}, \hspace{4pt} \forall n$.
If $E_n\supseteq E_{n+1}, \hspace{4pt} \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and exists $k\in \mathbb{N}$ st $\mu(E_k)<+\infty$, then $$ \mu(E_n)\overset{n}{\longrightarrow} \mu\left(\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} E_n\right)$$
Proof.
$(b)$ Define $A_n=E_k\setminus E_n, \hspace{3pt}\forall n\geq k.$
Then, $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}, \hspace{3pt}\forall n\geq k$ and so the sequence $(A_n)_{n\geq k}$ is increasing. Therefore, I can apply the continuity from below (that I've already proved) to $(A_n)_{n\geq k}$ and then I obtain
$$\mu(A_n)\overset{n}{\longrightarrow} \mu\left(\bigcup_{n\geq k}A_n\right)$$
In particular, using properties of measures, I have that:

$$\mu(A_n)=\mu(E_k\setminus E_n)=\mu(E_k)-\mu(E_n)$$
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\geq k}A_n\right)=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\geq k}(E_k\setminus E_n)\right)=\mu\left(E_k\setminus \left(\bigcap_{n\geq k}E_n\right)\right)=\mu(E_k)-\mu\left(\bigcap_{n\geq k}E_n\right)$$

So, equating the two equations, for $n\geq k$
$$\mu(E_k)-\mu(E_n)=\mu(E_k)-\mu\left(\bigcap_{n\geq k}E_n\right)$$
and because $\mu(E_k)<+\infty$, I can cancel it from both sides and obtain th thesis
$$\mu(E_n)=\mu\left(\bigcap_{n\geq k}E_n\right)=\mu\left(\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}E_n\right)$$
where the last equal follows because $(E_n)_n$ is a decreasing sequence.
Is this correct to the end? Precisely the last two steps. If it is not, I want to understand why it is not correct, so, anyone to help me? I can't figure out where it's wrong and I'm stuck.

Now It is almost good, but you are not “equating” the two equations, but replacing those expressions in the limit you obtained in the beginning ;)

We did it! Thank you.

You just need a small change in the end:
$$\mu(A_n)\overset{n}{\longrightarrow} \mu\left(\bigcup_{n\geq k}A_n\right)$$
that means
$$ \lim_n \mu(A_n) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n\geq k}A_n\right)$$
In particular, using properties of measures, I have that:
$$\mu(A_n)=\mu(E_k\setminus E_n)=\mu(E_k)-\mu(E_n)$$
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\geq k}A_n\right)=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\geq k}(E_k\setminus E_n)\right)=\mu\left(E_k\setminus \left(\bigcap_{n\geq k}E_n\right)\right)=\mu(E_k)-\mu\left(\bigcap_{n\geq k}E_n\right)$$
So, replacing the two equations in the limit, for $n\geq k$, we get
$$\mu(E_k)- \lim_n \mu(E_n) = \lim_n (\mu(E_k)-\mu(E_n)) =\mu(E_k)-\mu\left(\bigcap_{n\geq k}E_n\right)$$
Where the first equality follows because $\mu(E_k)$ does not depend on $n$. Now, because $\mu(E_k)<+\infty$, I can cancel it from both sides and obtain th thesis
$$\lim_n  \mu(E_n)=\mu\left(\bigcap_{n\geq k}E_n\right)=\mu\left(\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}E_n\right)$$
where the last equal follows because $(E_n)_n$ is a decreasing sequence.

Thank you very much!
